# Mingw64 Linker error when trying to include -lhid

Tags: c++, windows, linker, mingw, mingw-w64

I am upgrading from mingw32 to mingw64 and I have issues when linking my program. The linker option -lhid seems to not work as expected. I am using a VM with Win8 OS.

Code Snippet:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <hidsdi.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  GUID guidHID;
  HidD_GetHidGuid(&guidHID);
  return 0;
}
```

Console output:

```
C:\Users\[...]>where g++

C:\mingw-w64-7.3.0\i686-7.3.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev0\mingw32\bin\g++.exe

C:\Users\[...]>g++ test.cc -lhid
C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Temp\ccax2hjg.o:test.cc:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `HidD_GetHidGuid(_GUID*)@4'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

C:\Users\[...]>g++ test.cc
C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Temp\ccax2hjg.o:test.cc:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `HidD_GetHidGuid(_GUID*)@4'
```

This works fine if I use g++ in my old mingw32 install.
A point to note is that if I omit -lhid for the old install the linker complains about the impl version of the said function. Console output for old mingw:

```
C:\Users\[...]\Documents>where g++
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe

C:\Users\[...]\Documents>g++ test.cc

C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0HcYlz.o:test.cc:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `_imp__HidD_GetHidGuid@4'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

C:\Users\[...]\Documents>g++ test.cc -lhid

C:\Users\[...]\Documents>
```